# How to parse object to another component using fetch

Tags: reactjs

I need to be able to parse obj to another component called GuestForm.

However when i try to set obj.first_name i can see in the console that the the obj.first_name value is empty.

On top of having the object empty i would like to parse it to the component.

```
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect }  from 'react';
import GuestForm from '../../components/Guests/GuestForm.js';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from "axios";

function Edit() {
  
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [mode, setMode] = useState('edit');
  const [successMessage, setsuccessMessage] = useState('The guest has been edited successfully!');
  const [action, setAction] = useState('/guests/edit');
  const obj = {first_name: '', last_name: '', email: '', password: ''};

  const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*", 
    "Accept": "application/json"
  }

  const res = fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL + action, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers,
    body: JSON.stringify({data: {id: id}}),
   })
   .then((response) => response.json())
   .then((responseJson) => {
     //return responseJson.json.guest;
     obj.first_name = responseJson.json.guest.first_name;
   })
   .catch((error) => {
     console.error(error);
   });

   console.log(obj); // Empty value for first name here...

  return (
    <>
        <div className="container">
            <GuestForm mode={mode} successMessage={successMessage} obj={obj} action={action} />
        </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Edit;
```

GuestForm

Here the component GuestForm which should display first name value in the field

```
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect }  from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { Link, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

// react-bootstrap components
import {
  Button,
  Card,
  Form,
  Row,
  Col,
} from "react-bootstrap";
import axios from "axios";

import { toast } from 'react-toastify';

function GuestForm({mode, successMessage, obj, action}) {

  const history = useHistory();

  const [details, setDetails] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const [first_name, setFirstName] = useState(obj.first_name);
  const [last_name, setLastName] = useState(obj.last_name);
  const [email, setEmail] = useState(obj.email);
  const [password, setPassword] = useState(obj.password);

  const handleSave = e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      setLoading(true);
      axios({
        method: "POST",
        url: process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL + action,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8', "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*", "Accept": "application/json" },
        data: {
          data: obj
        }
      }).then(result => {
        if(result.data.json.error == false) {
            toast(successMessage, {
                position: "top-right",
                autoClose: 5000,
                hideProgressBar: false,
                closeOnClick: true,
                pauseOnHover: true,
                draggable: true,
                progress: undefined,
            });
            history.push('/dashboard/guests');
        }
        setDetails(result.data.json);
        setLoading(false);
      });
  };

  return (
    <>
    <div className="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1 className="mt-0 mb-4 green-color">{mode == 'edit'? <span>Edit</span>: 'New' } Guest</h1>
            </div>
        </div>

        <Form onSubmit={handleSave} autoComplete="off">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 mt-2">
                    <Form.Group>
                        <label htmlFor="exampleInputEmail1">
                        Email Address
                        </label>
                        <Form.Control
                        value={email} 
                        onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                        type="email"
                        autoComplete="off"
                        ></Form.Control>
                    </Form.Group>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 mt-2">
                <Form.Group>
                        <label>Password</label>
                        <Form.Control
                        value={password} 
                        onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                        type="password"
                        autoComplete="new-password"
                        ></Form.Control>
                    </Form.Group>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 mt-2">
                    <Form.Group>
                        <label>First Name</label>
                        <Form.Control
                        value={first_name} 
                        onChange={e => setFirstName(e.target.value)}
                        type="text"
                        autoComplete="off"
                        ></Form.Control>
                    </Form.Group>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 mt-2">
                    <Form.Group>
                        <label>Last Name</label>
                        <Form.Control
                        value={last_name} 
                        onChange={e => setLastName(e.target.value)}
                        type="text"
                        autoComplete="off"
                        ></Form.Control>
                    </Form.Group>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            {(details.guest && details.error ) && <div className="error-message mt-4 mb-1">{details.message}</div>}

            <Button
                className="btn-fill pull-right mt-3"
                type="submit"
                variant="info"
                disabled={loading}
            >
            {loading && <span>{mode == 'edit'? <span>SAVE CHANGES</span>: 'ADD' }...</span>}
            {!loading && <span>{mode == 'edit'? <span>SAVE CHANGES</span>: 'ADD' }</span>}
            </Button>
            <div className="clearfix"></div>
        </Form>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default GuestForm;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your `console.log` is showing up as empty is because you are setting the value of `obj.first_name` in an asynchronous callback, but the actual logging line will be executed synchronously before that asynchronous callback is called. If you were to instead add another `.then` to the chain and do the `console.log` in there, you would see the updated value. Here's a snippet that demonstrates what I mean:

```js
const obj = { a: 'b' };

Promise.resolve()
  .then(() => {
    obj.a = 'c';
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('async:', obj);
  });
  
console.log('sync:', obj);
```

If you want to send this value to `GuestForm`, you'll have to use a state variable that will be updated once the `fetch` call finishes. You also want to wrap this `fetch` call in a `useEffect`, so that calling `setObj` doesn't result in an endless loop (the fetch call causes the state update, which then causes the component to be re-rendered, which causes the fetch call to rerun, and so on). Something like:

```
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect }  from 'react';
import GuestForm from '../../components/Guests/GuestForm.js';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from "axios";

function Edit() {
  
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [mode, setMode] = useState('edit');
  const [successMessage, setsuccessMessage] = useState('The guest has been edited successfully!');
  const [action, setAction] = useState('/guests/edit');
  const [obj, setObj] = useState({first_name: '', last_name: '', email: '', password: ''});

  const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*", 
    "Accept": "application/json"
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const res = fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL + action, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: headers,
      body: JSON.stringify({data: {id: id}}),
     })
     .then((response) => response.json())
     .then((responseJson) => {
       //return responseJson.json.guest;
       const newObj = { ...obj, first_name: 
  responseJson.json.guest.first_name };
       setObj(newObj);
     })
     .catch((error) => {
       console.error(error);
     });
  }, []);

   console.log(obj); // This will now show the updated value (but will still have the default value on the initial render)

  return (
    <>
        <div className="container">
            <GuestForm mode={mode} successMessage={successMessage} obj={obj} action={action} />
        </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Edit;
```

To use the updated value in `GuestForm`, you need to make sure your state variable is updated when the passed in prop is updated. This is best achieved with a `useEffect`. Add this to your `GuestForm` component

```
useEffect(() => {
  setFirstName(obj.first_name);
}, [obj]);
```

This is necessary because you're duplicating the prop value with state variables in the child component. A more common pattern would be to pass both `obj` and `setObj` as props to `GuestForm` so that in the child you can modify the parent's state variable directly without creating a copy

Comment: Thanks mate, i just updated my post with the guestForm component, the actual fetch keeps doing api call (looping), do you know why?

Comment: Ah yes, I should've structured this in a `useEffect`, otherwise each call to `setObj` will cause the thing to rerun, and will endless loop

Comment: Can you help me with this? sorry at least i can understand what's going on

Comment: Yup, was just in the middle of editing my answer, should be good now

Comment: Thanks the infinity loop stopped, now i don't understand why first_name is empty in GuestForm component. function GuestForm({mode, successMessage, obj, action}) {

  const history = useHistory();

  const [details, setDetails] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const [first_name, setFirstName] = useState(obj.first_name);
  const [last_name, setLastName] = useState(obj.last_name);
  const [email, setEmail] = useState(obj.email);
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  console.log(first_name);

Comment: obj is not empty in guestForm but after the useState for first name then first name do not get initialized with the value

Comment: Since the fetch call happens asynchronously, the first value of `obj` will be the default value, which has `first_name` as an empty string. Once the call finishes and the state update happens, the value will now be updated. To deal with this you'll have to add a check to your `GuestForm` component that makes sure `first_name` has been set before trying to do anything. That way the empty value will be ignored, and once you receive the updated value you can now do your logic

Comment: Oh ok, so i have to set useState to be blank then i set it again with the obj.first_name? I'm not quite sure, thanks again for your time

Comment: Sort of, I added an edit explaining what I mean